# Invalid object name SQL select

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm trying to select items from two tables which share the same unique identifier. The select statment I am using is;'

```
select 
f1.[filmTitle],
f1.[filmImagePath],
f1.[filmRating],
f1.[filmPrice],
f2.[filmActors],
f2.[filmDesciption],
f2.[filmTrailer],
f2.[filmLength],
f2.[filmDirector],
f2.[filmCertificate] 
FROM film.[filmID] f1 
JOIN filmData.filmID f2 
ON f1.filmID = f2.filmID 
WHERE (f1.filmID = @ID)
```

Table 1 [named 'films'] has the columns; filmID, filmTitle, filmImagePath, filmRating, filmPrice.

Table 2 [named 'filmData'] has the columns; filmID,filmActors,filmDesciption, filmTrailer, filmLength, filmDirector, filmCertificate.

I get the error "Invalid object name 'films.filmID'."

Thanks

Comment: Check the names.. your code shows "from film.[filmID] f1" and you explain that table named "films"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table is called `films`. That is what you should be selecting from.

This:

```
FROM film.[filmID] f1 
JOIN filmData.filmID f2
```

Should be this:

```
FROM films f1 
JOIN filmData f2
```

What you're doing in your query is attempting to select a column from other columns.. which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: oh that simple eh :P I'm not great with SQL so I expected much worse, thanks for explaining what my query was doing also.

Comment: No problem. We all started out making this mistake I think. When learning what JOIN's were I certainly made this exact mistake assuming that you joined on a column directly.